# Shibboleth SSO redirect issue in public URL

Tags: url, redirect, public, shibboleth

There have an issue about SSO testing on public URL.

My SP would provide service on public site, it's hostname is x056.org.local, and I configured entryId as xx://sso.mypublic.com/shibboleth, sso.mypublic.com is a public url

After I logined in with Login page xx://sso.mypublic.com/secure/

and then start redirect to original URL, brower would go to xx://x056.org.local/secure/ but not https://sso.mypublic.com/secure/.

The issue is xx://x056.org.local/secure/ is not a public URL, terminal user can't access it so would got page can't access error.

Anyboay can help to check it? or other solution?

xx means https

=======================================================

Has followed the steps

```
1. download and instal sp on machine
2. include shibboleth's configuration into apache 2.1. into httpd.conf file add include "PATH/opt/path/etc/apache22"(if version is apache2.2, otherwise appropriate)
3. in apache22.config file add the location you want to secure - it would be /secure bydefault
4. in shibboleth2.xml file (in etc folder) put your entity id(application defaults element), ex https://mywebsite.com/shibboleth - this can be anything, not neccessary a real path
5. put entity id of your idp in sso element, in case of testshib it would be https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth
6. in the metadata provider put idp's metadata uri to your idp's metadata urn, incase testshib it would be http://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml
7. Download metadata from https://mywebsitehost.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata - here mywebsitehost would be a real host and rest path will be automatically configured by shibboleth - this path will download your sp's metadata file
8. Upload metadata file to testshib for register
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using passive authentication, make sure that your redirection-target that you set with the Login-Link is correct.
If you're using active authentication, you probably have to check your Apache(?)-VHost-Configuration.